# Handling string values when rounding a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame (`df`) that looks like

```
   DATE_OF_BIRTH           AGE
0     1974-03-28    43.0095412
1      NOT KNOWN     NOT KNOWN
2     1970-11-27    46.3419843
3     1974-05-09    42.8944168
4     1985-03-14    32.0474122
```

I would like to round the `AGE` column to 3 decimal places so the desired output would look like:

```
   DATE_OF_BIRTH        AGE
0     1974-03-28     43.010
1      NOT KNOWN  NOT KNOWN
2     1970-11-27     46.342
3     1974-05-09     42.894
4     1985-03-14     32.047
```

I have tried using

```
df['AGE'] = df['AGE'].round(3)
```

but when a string (like `NOT KNOWN`) is encountered then I get the  error:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

How can I handle strings when rounding a data-frame column?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest convert non numeric and not datetimes values to missing values with [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and  [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) for avoid mixed types - numeric/datetimes with strings - then numeric/datetimeslike functions failed:

```
df['DATE_OF_BIRTH'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_OF_BIRTH'], errors='coerce')
df['AGE'] = pd.to_numeric(df['AGE'], errors='coerce').round(3)
print (df)
  DATE_OF_BIRTH     AGE
0    1974-03-28  43.010
1           NaT     NaN
2    1970-11-27  46.342
3    1974-05-09  42.894
4    1985-03-14  32.047
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) to change to `numeric` and `errors='coerce'` to coerce the non numerics to `NaN`, then round and fillna with the non numerics, but in general, you should not mix dtypes in a series

```
df.AGE=pd.to_numeric(df.AGE,errors='coerce').round(3).fillna(df.AGE)
print(df)
```

Comment: hmmm, maybe the best add to answer not recomended ;)